# Customer Computer and WDS Driver Error

Tags: drivers, windows-server-2008-r2, network-adapter, desktop-computer

When attempting to run Windows Deployment Services on a client machine, I get an error stating that it doesn't have the driver for the NIC card that the client is using.

The machine I have was a custom made machine. I have no way of knowing what type/brand the NIC card is.

Here are a few things I do know:

1. ASUS is the motherboard and BIOS system for the computer.
2. The PXE / LAN technology referenced in the BIOS system is label as Intel.

I have been searching for drivers on the Intel website, but I am wondering how to identify what driver I need?

Comment: Look at the manual for the mainboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP said:

`> The PXE / LAN technology referenced in the BIOS system is label as Intel.`

What you are surely seeing is the PXE firmware banner displaying its PXE version compliance: v2.0 or v2.1. The PXE firmware is made by Intel and you can read "Intel" in that screen message but that tells nothing about your NIC "real" manufacturer.

I'd try to get the motherboard information and from there you can find the installed NIC alternatively you can also try installing your OS with [Serva](http://vercot.com/~serva/an/WindowsPXE1.html) surelly you'll face the same problem (missing NIC driver) but in Serva's case you can open a `console` and find the NIC data by looking at the log file

```
x:\Windows\inf\setupapi.app.log
```

there you can see something like

```
>>>  [DIF_SELECTBESTCOMPATDRV -PCI\VEN_10B7&DEV_9200&SUBSYS_010D1028&REV_78\4&19FD8D60]
>>>  Section start 2012/04/25 12:42:59.281
   cmd: winpeshl.exe 
    dvi: No class installer for 'Ethernet Controller'
     dvi: No CoInstallers found
     dvi: Default installer: Enter
     dvi:      {Select Best Driver}
!    dvi:           Selecting driver failed(0xe0000228)
     dvi:      {Select Best Driver - exit(0xe0000228)}
!    dvi: Default installer: failed!
!    dvi: Error 0xe0000228: There are no compatible drivers for this device.
<<<  Section end 2012/04/25 12:42:59.296
<<<  [Exit status: FAILURE(0xe0000228)]
```

This part of the log describes a NIC with a missing driver you can also see its `VEN_10B7&DEV_9200` that means VEN=10B7 DEV=9200 those numbers identify the NIC; google them and find your NIC drivers.

Please remember when dealing with "integrated" NICs is never a good idea looking for drivers on NIC manufacturer websites try the "Integrator" website instead. Motherboard and Notebook manufacturers many times use NICs with subtle differences that require their special drivers (I'm related to Serva development)